# Totalling scores and adding to a graded result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a ratings form that allows individuals to be scored and then placed into a graded group but I'm having difficulty working out how this can be done with jQuery or JavaScript.

For example, the first part of my form has this structure where the totals from each group should be written to the `CombinedScore` field.

```
<input id="Food1" name="Food" type="radio" value="5" />
<input id="Food2" name="Food" type="radio" value="10" />
<input id="Food3" name="Food" type="radio" value="15" />

<input id="Drink1" name="Drink" type="radio" value="5" />
<input id="Drink2" name="Drink" type="radio" value="10" />
<input id="Drink3" name="Drink" type="radio" value="15" />

<input name="CombinedScore" type="text" />
```

The second part should check the value of the combined score and place it in the appropriate group. For example

```
<input id="FoodDrinkGroup1" name="FoodDrinkGroup" type="radio" value="1-10" />
<input id="FoodDrinkGroup2" name="FoodDrinkGroup" type="radio" value="11-20" />
<input id="FoodDrinkGroup3" name="FoodDrinkGroup" type="radio" value="21-30" />
```

So, if someone scores 10 on food and 15 on drink, they should be added to the `21-30` `FoodDrinkGroup`.

In all I have three groups like this but I'm hoping if I can get it working for one, I should be able to apply the same code to the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using classes for different groups of items would make selectors more concise, but even with this markup you can do it like this

```
$(function() {
    // Part 1
    var sum = parseInt($('input[name="Food"]:checked').attr('value'));
    sum += parseInt($('input[name="Drink"]:checked').attr('value'));
    $('input[name="CombinedScore"]').val(sum);

    //Part 2
    $('input[name="FoodDrinkGroup"]').each(function(i, elem) {
        var range = $(elem).attr('value').split('-');
        if (sum >= range[0] && sum <= range[1]) {
            $(elem).attr('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AgjwD/)

Comment: I believe you should parseInt(value) before summing it. Otherwise they are strings.

Comment: Also, you can use `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following function, seems to be working. See the working live example here - http://jsfiddle.net/YUwUG/

```
function proc() {

    food = $('input[name=Food]:checked').val();
    drink = $('input[name=Drink]:checked').val();

    combined = parseInt(food) + parseInt(drink);

    $("#combined").val(combined);

    if (combined < 11) {
        $('#FoodDrinkGroup1').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else if (combined < 21) {
        $('#FoodDrinkGroup2').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else if (combined < 31) {
        $('#FoodDrinkGroup3').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }

}
```

Comment: a) Your fiddle lacks the "javascript" part; b) there is no `'#combined'` defined in primary html code; c) you're missing `else` before last `if`, hence the last group will always get selected

Comment: Ah, not sure, where does the code GO, it vanished. Anyways, thanks for pointing out the else.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but thought I'd show the code I produced. This just uses a bit of math to determine what group and therefore what element index it should select.

```
var total = 0;

$('input[name=Food]:checked, input[name=Drink]:checked')
 .each(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value);
});

var index = parseInt(total / 11);

$('[name=CombinedScore]').val(total);

$('input[name=FoodDrinkGroup]').eq(index).prop('checked', true);
```

**Working live fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/garreh/5j7Jd/

Comment: Thanks for the example. I tried this out and yes it does work in this example however it fails to accurately rank the scores if the ranges are increased from 5, 10, 15 to 1 through 12. This wasn't part of the original question so in this context your solution works well.

Comment: If they increase by 5 then change `var index = parseInt(total / 6);` -- obviously this technique relies on their being a mathmatical pattern to your ranges, so mkilmanas technique although longer is more versatile.